# get array of objects where boolean is true

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

this is my collection

```
{
      "_id": "bRu9ExERzz8PCDwRp",
      "persian_title": "عنوان پارسی",
      "english_title": "english title",
      "price": 5000,
      "offer_price": 2000,
"free_for_all": false,
      "is_offer": false,
      "author_id": "JH3hJGsuYFnRLFLWY"
      "Seasons": [
        {
          "title": "intro",
          "free_for_all": false,
          "Episodes": [
            {
              "title": "first episode",
              "length": "12",
              "url": "0.mp4",
              "free_for_all": true
            },
            {
              "title": "second episode",
              "length": "05",
              "url": "1.mp4",
              "free_for_all": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i'm trying to get Seasons , episodes where free_for_all is true.
tried this but it doesn't work.

```
db.courses.find({_id:"bRu9ExERzz8PCDwRp"}, {
"Seasons": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
            "Episodes": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "free_for_all": true,
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

the result is just like this query :

```
db.courses.find({_id:"bRu9ExERzz8PCDwRp"})
```

how can i get only free seasons and episodes?

Comment: well, if you are finding by id then you will not get anything that doesn't match that id ;-) -- find operates on collections. What you seem to be looking for are subsets of arrays within collection elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous regarding the desired outcome for free season with non-free episodes, and vice versa, free episodes in non-free seasons. So I'm assuming you want only episodes that are free and are part of a free season. That's what the following will give you (not tested):

```
_.reduce(db.courses.findOne({_id:"bRu9ExERzz8PCDwRp"}).Seasons, function(all, s) {
     if (s.free_for_all) {
         all = _.reduce(s.Episodes, function(memo, e) {
              if (e.free_for_all) memo.push(e);
              return memo;
         }, all);
     }
     return all;
}, []);
```

If you want all episodes that are free or part of a free season:

```
_.reduce(db.courses.findOne({_id:"bRu9ExERzz8PCDwRp"}).Seasons, function(all, s) {
     if (s.free_for_all) {
        all = all.concat(s.Episodes);
     } else {
         all = _.reduce(s.Episodes, function(memo, e) {
              if (e.free_for_all) memo.push(e);
              return memo;
         }, all);
     }
     return all;
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i want to get free seasons (doesn't matter if it contains non-free episode, just return all episodes) and get free episodes of non-free seasons. and the code you wrote throws this error : `Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: memo is not defined`

Comment: do you have seasons that are `free_for_all` which also include free episodes.

Comment: Yes, this is different from what you describe in your comment you want. I may have time to fix the answer, but I'm sure you'll be able to take it from here.

Comment: how can i get the result as an single object like the result of `courses.find({_id:"bRu9ExERzz8PCDwRp"});` this is how the result looks like now :  http://i.imgur.com/MaWr8eZ.png